# ssh to list of nodes in bash

Tags: bash, ssh

I need to ssh several nodes in a list.
My code, when I run each command manually, works, but in a bash script, it does not.

```
sjc_nodes=$(kubectl get nodes -l nodeGroup=gpu --no-headers -o wide | awk '{print $1}' | sed -n -e 1,3p)

for sjc_node in "${sjc_nodes}"
do
echo $sjc_nodes;
ssh -F $HOME/.ssh/ssh_config userme@"$sjc_node.ssh-server.net" "nvidia-smi"
done;
```

Expected:

```
node1 node2 node3

nvidia-smi tests
```

Actual:

```
node1 node2 node3
usage: nc [-46CDdFhklNnrStUuvZz] [-I length] [-i interval] [-M ttl]
  [-m minttl] [-O length] [-P proxy_username] [-p source_port]
  [-q seconds] [-s source] [-T keyword] [-V rtable] [-W recvlimit] [-w timeout]
  [-X proxy_protocol] [-x proxy_address[:port]]       [destination] [port]
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

My config file is below

```
cat ~/.ssh/ssh_config

HashKnownHosts no
 ServerAliveInterval 60
CanonicalizeHostname yes
CanonicalDomains server-ssh.net
ConnectionAttempts 100
ForwardAgent yes
StrictHostKeyChecking no
UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
user userme
Host *.server-ssh.net 10.*
  Compression yes
  ProxyCommand ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=No" userme@1.2.3.4 nc %h %p
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting the variable in quotes makes it just one word, so you don't loop over all the nodes. Get rid of the quotes so that the shell will split the variable into words.

```
for sjc_node in $sjc_nodes
```

This is the exception to the general rule that you should always quote variables.

Comment: awesome! I wish we create a cheat sheet to real time use cases of scripting and coding.